# Text Maths Equation To Formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have created a formula to take a maths equation and replace each x value with the current cell value. Here is that formula, where `A1` is the formula and `L2:L30` is the range of values to insert into the formula:

```
=MAP(L2:L30; LAMBDA(x; SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE($A$1; "x "; "*" & x); "x"; "*" & x & "^")))
```

Here is what the equation looks like: `-0,0547x2 + 1,1581x + 6,2501`

And after applying the formula (for 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, etc.):
[image: After applying formula]

I know I could do this easily with VBA, but I'd like to avoid converting to an xlsm. So I'm wondering if there's any way to convert these text formulas so they evaluate, without manually copy-pasting and adding an =?

Comment: So you have a range with the equations written as text, and you want to evaluate them?   If this is the case, is it the same equation with a different "x" value?

Comment: =CONCAT("=",A1), copy/paste values somewhere, select that area, Ctrl+H, replace = with =

Comment: @PeterT Precisely, although the x in the equation is simply text not the actual variable... super misleading of me to write the formula that way apologies

Comment: @Alexander I have posted an answer, try it once

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya Will try in the morning and let you know, thanks. Out of curiosity, what OS/excel version are you running as the font looks different?

Comment: Read and deleting now.... @MayukhBhattacharya

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something along the lines of creating a defined named function <kbd>EVAL( )</kbd> which corresponds to the following.

```
=LAMBDA(α,EVALUATE(α))
```

---

[image]

---

Steps:

- From <kbd>Formulas</kbd> Tab.
- Click on <kbd>Define Name</kbd>.
- Enter the name as <kbd>EVAL</kbd>.
- Scope will be <kbd>Workbook</kbd>.
- Refers To: will be

---

```
=LAMBDA(α,EVALUATE(α))
```

---

- Press OK.

---

[image]

---

Now, apply the formula in cell <kbd>B2</kbd>

```
=EVAL(
    MAP(
        H2:H11,
        LAMBDA(x,
            SUBSTITUTE(
                SUBSTITUTE(
                    A1,
                    "x ",
                    "*" & x
                ),
                "x",
                "*" & x & "^"
            )
        )
    )
)
```

---

Make required changes to the ranges as per your suit.

Comment: This works, however it does still require me to convert the workbook to a macro-enabled (xlsm) format

Answer (score 0):

If I'm interpreting your needs correctly, you have a range of cells that have a text formula that you want to evaluate. My solution here makes a few assumptions:

1. The variable value is ***always*** in the same place in the formula
2. The text formula is the same on each line, only the "X" value changes

If this is the case, then consider the following...

[image]

First, you have to identify/extract the "X" value from the text string. The formula in Column B is

```
=MID(A2,FIND("^",A2,1)+1,(FIND("+",A2)-FIND("^",A2))-1)
```

After that, it's a matter of using that value in the formula itself, so Column C is

```
=-POWER(0.0547,NUMBERVALUE(B2))+1.1581*B2+6.2501
```